# Help! Interfacing LCD with Arduino using 8255A Intel peripherals

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

I'm new to all this stuff and for the past two days, I have been trying to interface a 16x2 LCD to an Arduino Uno using an Intel 8255A component without any luck. The problem is, how can I attach or set the LCD's pins <> to the unknown pins of the 8255A.

Is it even possible?

Thanks for any kind of help.[image]

Comment: 8255!!!! Where did you find it?!?!

Comment: haha from this https://www.google.com/search?q=8255A+intel&biw=1366&bih=640&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLp5aD3qLMAhXsJZoKHRJrBUMQ_AUICSgD#imgrc=KVpfZFZBqOuJlM%3A

Comment: What are `unknowing pins`?

Comment: i'm talking about the i/o of 8255 component, they are unknowing for Arduino IDE, how can i make them as inputs for LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2),  this is my problem :/

Comment: @HamzaTST i meant where you found the actual component. I haven't seen one, much less used one, since 1985!

Comment: also, why are you bothering with the 8255 and not driving the display directly with the arduino pins? Do you plan to connect it on some other system, such as an intel 8085? :)

Comment: yes this is why, because i have much less pins to connect such LCD and some others component, you have an idea @JayEye ;)

Comment: I'd use something like a Teensy 3.2, it has 30+ gpio pins, and much easier to come by than the 8055 (again, unless you want to attach this to some retrocomputing project).

Comment: Thanks @JayEye for your advice, this is what im gonna do :)

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to use 8255 pins as parameters to the the LiquidCrystal library without making substantial changes to either the library or the Arduino core.

The reason is that to configure or change a pin on the 8255, you will need to go through a series of operations manipulating the ATmega pins to which the 8255's `microprocessor bus interface` is connected.  You can learn about the necessary operations by reading the 8255 data sheet.  Also keep in mind that the 8255 does not have per-pin configuration - rather, the first two ports must each be either entirely inputs or entirely outputs, while there third port can be split in half.

Once you know how to set a pin, you will need to have the liquid crystal functionality trigger these operations.

One approach would be to create a heavily modified version of the library which knows how to work through the 8255.

Another would be to create a modified version of the Arduino core which has additional pin numbers corresponding to the 8255's pins, and generates code which does the necessary intermediate bus operations to access them.  However this will be quite challenging - you have to make sure the intermediate code gets in there in all paths, and figure out how it will handle cases where code tries to set pins that must have the same mode to conflicting modes.

As others have said, you would practically be better off using a different MCU with more I/Os - either an Arduino Mega, or one of the ARM-based boards.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Stratton for your advice, this is what im gonna do :)